# IE 6 Export Menu size issue

Tags: internet-explorer-6, highcharts

In IE 6 Highstock chart exports menu width is not getting properly displayed,  its taking the maximum width but lesser than the chart width whereas it has to take the width based on the menu items as in IE 8/9.

The same is working fine in IE 8/9.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to fix it for me was to put this in my css:

```
.highcharts-contextmenu{
    width: 200px;
}
```

works for me with IE6->10

hope this will help